# Find the home path of an item

Tags: sitecore-query

I have custom button in Core database and I want to get the home path of an item.

This is the item `/sitecore/content/Test/Retail/TestShop/home/whats-on/event-1`

This is the home path '/sitecore/content/Test/Retail/TestShop/home'

I am able to find the home item using the following code

```
  var item = "/sitecore/content/Test/Retail/TestShop/home/whats-on/event-1";
  string split = "home";
  int index = item.LastIndexOf(split);
  if (index > 0)
     item = item.Substring(0, index+ split.Length);
```

Is there a better way finding item's home item?

Comment: Did you try string homeitempath = Sitecore.Context.Site.RootPath + Sitecore.Context.Site.StartItem

Comment: @RamanGupta This logic will not work because I am doing changes in the custom button I created in the core database so the  Sitecore.Context.Database will always be core db.

Comment: in that case you can use content Database, Sitecore.Context.ContentDatabase.GetItem(site.RootPath + site.StartItem)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are working with a multisite structure, then first of all you'll need to loop through all the configured sites and get the home page of current item.

```
// Current item
var item = Sitecore.Context.Item;

//Since you're working on Core DB, so Sitecore.Context.Database will return core, instead you can use ContentDatabase
Sitecore.Data.Database contentDB = Sitecore.Context.ContentDatabase;

// loop through all configured sites
foreach (var site in Sitecore.Configuration.Factory.GetSiteInfoList())
  {
      // get this site's home page item
      var homePage = contentDB.GetItem(site.RootPath + site.StartItem);

      // if the item lives within this site, this is our context site
      if (homePage != null && homePage.Axes.IsAncestorOf(item))
         {
            // Write your logic. This is homePage for your current item.
         } 
}
```

Comment: This logic will not work because I am doing changes in the custom button I created in the core database so the  Sitecore.Context.Database will always be core db.

Comment: edited the answer